# Passing the post id as a parameter

Tags: discussion, feature-request, hyperlinks, post-id

Is it possible to pass the post id as a parameter? i.e. to use something like

> meta.stackoverflow.com/?posts=1234

in place of

> meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1234

or

> meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/1234

---

Edit:

Here is a use case:

Sometimes I want to use URL shortening services like [j.mp](http://j.mp) in places like twitter. They give a short URL for a URL, so right now one needs a different short URL for each question. With parameters one could use a single nice short one (e.g. [j.mp/MetaSO](http://j.mp/MetaSO)) and then add a parameter for each post, something like `j.mp/MetaSO?id=1234`.

Comment: I'm curious why you're trying to do this (where the path won't work), can you provide a use case?

Comment: @Nick, done. :)

Comment: Interesting!  Seems like it would be a simple URL rewrite (or iis config in this case)

Comment: Man am I tired of obfuscating URLs! Why can't you just use the real one instead?

Comment: @CodyGray Too long for Twitter?

Comment: Great opportunity for someone to register a SO short domain :D

Answer (score 3):

Currently, this is not possible. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I have added the use case I had in mind to the question.